# iPhone 6s 3D Touch Support Request for iOS Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

As many of you may know, Apple's latest phone, the [iPhone 6s](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/), has a force-sensitive display assembly, dubbed [3D Touch](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/3d-touch/).

I find 3D Touch very useful and know that others do too, but the Stack Exchange app has yet to be updated with 3D Touch support, I can't even so much as preview a link using "Peek and Pop".

I know that I would really like 3D Touch support in the SE iOS app and I'm pretty sure that many other iPhone 6s owners would appreciate it, too, especially since it is quickly becoming standard in stock and 3rd-party iPhone apps.

If anyone reading this has the ability to do so, could you add 3D Touch gesture support to a future version of the iOS Stack Exchange app (could this already be in the works?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be implemented in 1.4.4, coming out in February.

I've gone ahead and added 3D Touch previews to the common lists:

- Questions
- Tags
- Users
- Favorite Questions
- Inbox
- Achievements

This should allow you to more quickly process these lists.  I wanted to add previews to links in post bodies but that is a royal mess for a few reasons:

- Turning on 3D Touch with the native `-[UIWebView setAllowsLinkPreview:]` only lets you display links in a Safari view, so links to questions would not go to the right location.
- When trying to manually observe touch events on the web view with `UIViewControllerPreviewing`, something in the web view blocks the gesture from getting recognized.
- If I wanted to hack web view preview views, the only public API I could actually swizzle is `-[SFSafariViewController initWithURL:]`, which would be a mess, and I'm running into other issues where it breaks scrolling.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.